# Merge nested array and regular array by first element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to merge a regular array array into a nested array such that a given element of a row in the nested array is replaced with each element in the regular array but can't compile the logic into a method e.g:

```
a1 = [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0]]

a2 = [1,1,1]

=> [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]] or [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

So far I have:

```
 a1[0][0, a2[0]] = a2[0]
 a1[1][0, a2[1]] = a2[1]
 a1[2][0, a2[1]] = a2[2]
```

Which gives the required result but this needs to be wrapped in a method such that any array sizes can be used.

Comment: Use `zip` with `map`. Or `map.with_index` on `a1` referencing `a2` with the block index parameter.

Comment: You could improve your example by making the elements more varied. For example, `a1 = [[0,1], [2,3],[4,5]]` and `a2 = [6,7,8]`. Also, it's best to ask for a specific return value for your example, rather than "this or that". If you specify "this", the return value for "that" can often be easily deduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` (with `first` or `last`, depending on which element from `a1` you want to fetch) and `zip`

```
a1.map(&:first).zip(a2)
# => [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/repls/BigheartedMustyTrex)

Comment: Consider putting that in the form of a method `def m(a1,a2,a1_index)...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, that was exactly what I needed